# Long wire antenna end fed random length folded back on incline

Tags: antenna-theory, wire-antenna, end-fed-antenna

Trying to lengthen my 10mtr. end fed to 39 metres in length. To do this I need the first leg (10mtr.) to run at a lower height approx (5mtr)turning back on a dog leg, and the final 29 meters then gaining height to approx. 9 metres high to of Gable end of house.
Observing the correct Unun and correct installation which I have already with the 10 meter wire.
My question is would the fold back, although climbing in height interfere with radiating correctly.

I can not find anything which suggests its unwise.

Thanks  for any input.
CHRIS.

Comment: Welcome to hamSE, Chris. I hope we can answer your question. A "stick figure" diagram would be very helpful.

Comment: The answer to your question depends on the frequency of interest. Length 10 meters plus 29 meters makes a high-impedance horizontal antenna for wavelength 58 meters with a vertical matching line. For lower frequencies it is a poor but usable top-load variant. Is the antenna meant for reception or also for transmission?

Comment: It was for transmit and receive on lower frequencies ie. 3.550. However, I acknowledge your comments thank you, and now considering simply a 29 mtr. end fed wire in a vertical > shape. (one above the other >  ) The feed end at the lower end. approx. 4.8 mtr. high.  With the height rising to 7 mtr. Your thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: That is important information, the frequency and TX/RX-use. The half-wave antenne, the horizontal part, is ok for skywave. The vertical part is connected to a high-impedance feedpoint and the current in the vertical part is low. This L-shape CAN have the advantage that the matching in this vertical bended line causes a higher-than-50 Ohm base point impedance. Then efficiency is higher (lower loss in earth system) and matching to 50 Ohm requires a tuner. Low angle radiation is poor; skywave is good.